# How to retrieve data from db with laravel as count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello I have this function:

```
public function readData(){
$TableB1 = \DB::table('users')
->join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
->join('meetings', 'users.id', '=', 'meetings.owned_by_id')
->select(
    'users.name as name',
    'group_user.user_id as id',
    'groups.name as groupname',
    \DB::raw('(
        SELECT COUNT(meetings.id) FROM meetings GROUP BY meetings.owned_by_id
    ) as meetings')
)
return $TableB1;

}
```

I retrieve some data from database and return them and use AJAX Call to use them later

The problem is I have a table called `users` and another tabled called `meetings`.

I want to know how many `meetings` every `user` done everyday.

So to do this I add:

```
\DB::raw('( SELECT COUNT(meetings.id) FROM meetings GROUP BY meetings.owned_by_id) as meetings')
```

But when i run it I get this error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'meetings' in 'field list' (SQL: select users.name as name, group_user.user_id as id, groups.name as groupname, meetings = ( SELECT COUNT(meetings.id) FROM meetings GROUP BY meetings.owned_by_id ) from users inner join group_user on users.id = group_user.user_id inner join groups on groups.id = group_user.group_id inner join meetings on users.id = meetings.owned_by_id) –

I can't seem to find the problem. What i want to achieve is [this](https://ibb.co/MZnx0BK)

Thank you very much

Comment: did you read about relations in laravel? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships. about eloquent? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent
so, at start you should refactor your code to laravel-way